# What are the pros and cons of selling the ring to either Svea or Harold? (A Fortunate Find)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

In the Falskaar quest, [A Fortunate Find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Lx3.jpg), I am given the option of either selling the ring to Harold or selling it to Svea.

What are the pros (rewards, other advantages, etc.) and cons of selling the ring to either Harold or Svea? Feel free to post unhidden spoilers.

[image: 'A Fortunate Find' quest journal]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about any long-term ramifications (I doubt there are any) but...

If you give the ring to Harold (actually it says you'll sell him the ring), he'll thank you and reward you with 100g. Your journal will update that he headed for the docks immediately to return to his family in Skyrim but I found him still lounging around the inn a day later, swilling ale and munching on a hunk of bread.

Reload, give the ring to Svea ('scuse me, "sell" the ring to her)... she thanks you, gives you a 300g reward and asks you to take the ring and armor to Rangarr to have it repaired.

Interestingly, at this point I saw Harold headed out of town, maybe going to the docks to return to his family? I would have gladly given him some money myself to help them out but I couldn't interact with him in any way.

Anyway, after waiting around for about 3 hrs, you pick up the armor and take it back to Svea, who gives you another 100g reward and asks you to present it to Gabrial for her. Guess she has a crush on him.  :)